# Laravel routes not catching my angular $http.get function

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am starting to build an app with a Laravel backend and an AngularJS front-end. All is going swimmingly so far apart from I cannot get my routes file to pick up on mt $http get requests. It returns fine with just the base url ("/") in the get, but when I add verbs in it doesn't work at all.

Here is my app.js AngularJS file which makes requests:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $http) {
$http.get("/laravel-old/here").success(function(todos) {
    $scope.todos = todos;
});

$scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
        count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
}
}
```

And here is my routes file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get("todos", function() {
    return Todo::all();
});

Route::get("here", function() {
    return "upi are here";
});
?>
```

The first route ("/") works fine and returns whatever I want it to, but when I change the get request to one of the other two as follows:

```
http.get("/laravel-old/here").success(function(todos) {
```

this is not picked up and I get a :

```
404 Not Found1ms    
angular.min.js (line 78)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localh**t/laravel-old/here"
```

My Laravel installation is in a sub-folder on my server called 'laravel-old'. Could this be anything to do with it?

THanks

Comment: Do you have a proper .htaccess file in your public folder?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? You have `laravel-old/public`, `laravel-old/app`, etc? Have you changed any config to make Laravel work with http://localhost/laravel-old/ instead of http://localhost? If so you might want to explain in your question too.

Comment: Yeah I do not see a route for `/laravel-old/here`, so I would assume you _should_ be getting a 404 error.  I do see a route for `/here`, though.

Comment: Hi, I have an untouched .htaccess file in my public folder. My installation is in a folder on the server called laravel-old. I haven't changed my config at all to work with the sub-folder. How do I do this? Thanks for your help